# Magento2: The meaning of '${ $.$data.(something) }' and how it works?

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs

We will see `${ $.$data.rowIndex }` in `cms_page_listing.xml` like below.

```
<item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
```

In `Magento/Cms/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/PageActions.php`, we also could find a `${ $.$data.title }`.

```
'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a ${ $.$data.title } record?')
```

I can guess it is a way to get data, but what is the detailed meaning of `${ $.$data.(something) }`? And how it works?

---

### 2017-10-16

Thanks the answer of PareshaU, we know it is a [Template Literals in Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_template_literals.html).

But, the official guide is **too general**, anyone could give some **special instructions**?

1. What's the content of `$.$data` and where its content come from?
2. What is the work process of `$.$data`? For example, the `${ $.$data.rowIndex }` in `cms_page_listing.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Template Literals in Magento.
You can read more about it from here.[enter link description here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_template_literals.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the official guide is too general, could you give some special instructions? What's the content of `$.$data` and where its content come from?